# Rapidly develop GUI for command line

Tags: linux, user-interface, command-line-arguments

I am looking for a software which would help me quickly build GUI (eg. HTML pages). When selecting different option from the GUI (eg. HTML forms), those options would *magically* turn into command line options. Eg: my GUI would allow me to select:

- Select input filename: inputfn
- Select output filename: outputfn
- Set Option1 to ON
- Set Option2 to OFF
- Set Option3 to value '42'
- ...

When clicking on 'Submit', this user input would turn into something like:

```
$ cmd_line --input $inputfn --output $outputfn --option1-on --option2-off --option3=42
```

I imagine I would need to write up a simple XML (YAML?) configuration file, to describe the simple layout and command line specificity (radio button, text fields ...).

Am I dreaming or is there something like this available ?

Comment: `gtkdialog` should be able to help you get that done with bash scripting and glade (xml). Check out http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/200910/page21.html

Comment: Please add tags for your operating system - I guess unix/linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31172/need-an-interface-for-a-gui-shell-script-more-powerful-than-zenity) seems to ask almost exactly what you want.

The top solution of using [YAD](http://code.google.com/p/yad/) seems to cover your requisites.

For example the following one liner:

```
data="$(yad --title="Desktop entry editor" --text="Simple desktop entry editor" --form --field="Type:CB" --field="Name" --field="Generic name" --field="Comment" --field="Command:FL" --field="Icon" --field="In terminal:CHK" --field="Startup notify:CHK" "Application" "Name" "Generic name" "This is the comment" "/usr/bin/yad" "yad" FALSE TRUE --button="WebUpd8:2" --button="gtk-ok:0" --button="gtk-cancel:1")"
```

creates a dialog containing:

- text fields
- dropdown selections
- checkboxes
- buttons

that looks like:

[image]

The output is all put on yad stdout and `echo "$data"` looks something like:

```
Application|Name|Generic name|This is the comment|/usr/bin/yad|yad|FALSE|TRUE|
```

Now you can "parse" the output with some cmdline tool such as `cut` or `awk`:

```
a="$(echo "$data" | cut -d"|" -f1)"
b="$(echo "$data" | cut -d"|" -f1)"
```

Then there is just application logic left to you.

Ubuntu install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yad
```

#### EDIT: focusing on the convertion of GUI to command line options

After receiving a downvote, I think I interpreted the answer the wrong way. The key point he wants is conversion from GUI to cmdline options interface.

I do not know of an existing solution, and since after 7 bounty days still no answer, we can assume that there is no existing solution.

Therefore, the best we can do is help the OP create a solution himself.
I believe that since there are not that many command line option cases, a reasonably small script will be sufficient.

Here goes a Python + Tk example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog

class Option(object):
    def __init__(self, optype, name, widget=Tkinter.Entry):
        self.optype = optype
        self.name = name
        if self.optype == 'switch':
            self.widget = Tkinter.Checkbutton
        else:
            self.widget = widget

## INPUT -------------------------------------------------------
options = [
    Option("key-value", "--text="),
    Option("switch", "-s"),
    Option("positional", "pos0"),
    Option("positional", "pos1", tkFileDialog.askopenfilename),
]
## END -------------------------------------------------------

def askopenfilename(filename):
    filename.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename())

# Build command
def ok_func():
    cmd = "cmd_line"
    for option in options:
        if option.optype == "key-value":
            val = tkvars[option.name].get()
            if val:
                cmd += ' '
                cmd += '%s"%s"' % (option.name, val)
        elif option.optype == "switch":
            cmd += ' '
            if tkvars[option.name].get() == 1:
                cmd += option.name
        elif option.optype == "positional":
            val = tkvars[option.name].get()
            if val:
                cmd += ' '
                cmd += val
    print cmd


tkvars = {}
app = Tkinter.Tk()
grid = Tkinter.Frame()
row = 0

# Build GUI
for option in options:
    Tkinter.Label(grid, text=option.name).grid(row=row, column=0, sticky='W')
    if option.widget == Tkinter.Entry:
        tkvars[option.name] = Tkinter.StringVar()
        widget = Tkinter.Entry(
            grid,
            textvariable=tkvars[option.name]
        )
    elif option.widget == Tkinter.Checkbutton:
        tkvars[option.name] = Tkinter.IntVar()
        widget = Tkinter.Checkbutton(
            grid,
            variable = tkvars[option.name],
            onvalue = 1
        )
    elif option.widget == tkFileDialog.askopenfilename:
        tkvars[option.name] = Tkinter.StringVar()
        widget = Tkinter.Button(
            grid,
            text='Browse',
            command=lambda: askopenfilename(tkvars[option.name])
        )
    widget.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='W')
    row += 1

grid.pack()
Tkinter.Button(app, text="ok", command=ok_func).pack()
Tkinter.Button(app, text="quit", command=app.quit).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

To run on Ubuntu 12.04 first do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Command generated for the screenshot:

```
cmd_line --text="asdf" -s qwer /path/to/file
```

Behaviour:

- if the value of `--text=` is empty then it is omitted
- switches only appear if the corresponding checkbox is checked

If you want to implement a new feature on top of that code, I recommend you do it [here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/python/blob/d07f2a330278eae2ecec589b76c46f2e1b0e453f/bin/gui-to-cmdline.py).
If it gets good enough, lets split to a new repo and make it pip installable.

Comment: That seems very close to what I was looking for. Still need to code the application logic and make sure to map yad graphical tool to the low level command line tool that will be executed.

Comment: Downvoters please explain so I can improve the info.

Comment: yad is low level compared to what I asked initially. Imagine having to code an application for -say- djpeg. There is no easy way to say that option '-outfile' requires a user input of type filename. All this boilerplate code is copy/pasted if I ever want to code an application for now cjpeg...

Comment: @malat Saying that an option requires a filename is possible: in `--field="Command:FL"` `FL` indicates that it expects a path, it shows on the GUI a button that opens up a file browser. I do agree however that the conversion to command line arguments could be more automatic.

Comment: @malat please check if the edit comes closer to what you wanted.